# How to write Active Element event is Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was struggling with an IE issue to overcome an input cursor remains visible when behind a div with z-index. I found a answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54029463/text-cursor-from-input-field-remains-visible-when-behind-dropdown-menu-in-ie), but wanted to convert it into jquery code.

JavaScript Core:

```
document.querySelector('.main-nav').addEventListener('mouseenter', function(){
  document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

JQuery: What I try...

```
$('body').on('mouseenter', '.main-nav', function() {
     document.activeElement.blur();
});
```

when I run this line on IE console getting following error.
I'm not sure about it. Please help me to convert it.

> The object doesn't support property or method 'on'

Comment: And the problem is...?

Comment: Do you think it should work? Sorry, I don't have more scope to run for the unit test.

Comment: Your jQuery code works fine. Not any issue.

Comment: But I'm getting error when try to run the codes in IE console, like "Object doesn't support property or method 'on'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'on'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26784268/javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-on)

Comment: replace '$' sign with 'jQuery' word.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? And is the issue specific to IE, or is IE the only browser you tested on?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the variant in jQuery:

```
$( ".main-nav" ).mouseenter(function() {
  $(':focus').blur();
});
```